# await Asyncstorage returns a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using a helper function to get the token from Asyncstorage and add it to the axios header but instead it gives a promise. My function is like this:

```
const getToken = async () => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token")
    return token
};
```

Comment: Async functions return promises, your code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some information about how to handle promises:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

I believe the parameter of the callback that you pass to `.then` will receive the value that your asynchronous function "returns."

Answer (score -1):

you are awaiting the token, it's supposed to return a promise. the correct way is:

```
async function getToken() {
  return await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
}
```

OR

```
const getToken = async () => {
  return await AsyncStorage.getItem("token")    
};
```